# Django Haystack. And, or in search queryset

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack, pysolr

Using: Haystack and Sorl.

I need to make a search queryset to search products by filter.

Firstly, I need to filter only products based on my site (Django site framework). So I do:

```
sqs = sqs.filter(site=site.pk)
```

It returns such search query:

```
site:(6)
```

OK.

Then I need to filter by attributes:

```
sqs = sqs.filter(attribute_codes='power', attribute_values__range=(20, 30))
sqs = sqs.filter(attribute_codes='power', attribute_values__range=(40, 50))
```

And it generates such query:

```
(site:(6) AND attribute_codes:(power) AND attribute_values:(["20" TO "30"]) AND attribute_values:(["40" TO "50"]))
```

But, I need to make a query like this:

```
(site=6) AND ((attributes1) OR (attributes2))
```

So I tried to change filtering by attributes to `filter_or`:

```
 sqs = sqs.filter_or(attribute_codes='power', attribute_values__range=(20, 30))
sqs = sqs.filter_or(attribute_codes='power', attribute_values__range=(40, 50))
```

And the result is:

```
(site:(6) OR (attribute_codes:(power) AND attribute_values:(["20" TO "30"])) OR (attribute_codes:(power) AND attribute_values:(["40" TO "50"])))
```

But I need else:

```
    (site=6) AND ((attributes1) OR (attributes2))
```

So, how to do this?
Help me, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Django's queryset `Q` object, django haystack has a `SQ` object, which allows using `|` and `&` operators in filtering

```
sqs = sqs.filter(site=6)
sqs = sqs.filter(SQ(attribute_codes='power') | SQ(attribute_values__range=(20, 30))
```

or

```
sqs = sqs.filter(
    SQ(site=6) & (SQ(attribute_codes='power') | SQ(attribute_values__range=(20, 30))
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help